# USB audio device not working because error in samping rate

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio

I have a problem with my USB audio device (Fiio BTR5) not outputting sound. I used to make it work but now it stops working. After some inspection, I found the problem is that, I specified the sampling rates in the file  `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` to be 192000kHZ (I also tried others but the same problem occurs) by doing:

> default-sample-rate = 192000
> alternate-sample-rate = 48000

but when I check the device in `/proc/asound/BTR5/stream0`, I saw this:

```
Playback:
  Status: Running
    Interface = 1
    Altset = 1
    Packet Size = 288
    Momentary freq = 192004 Hz (0x18.0020)
    Feedback Format = 16.16
```

My interpretation from this message is that the device is recognized, but the frequency is problematic, because the device recognizes 192000HZ, not 192004Hz. NOTE that the number of 192004 is random, because sometimes I also see 192002, 192003. Can anyone help me understand how to fix this problem? Very much appreciate it. Thank you.

Additional information: Ubuntu version: 22.04